# is it possible to use Class CoordCartesian object to plot a rectangle in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggproto object of class CoordCartesian  from ggplot2.
I created it with the line below;

```
Africablock<- list(coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-20,60), ylim=c(-38,25)))
```

I'm using it to plot a rectangle over an area of a bigger map as below, where I've explicitly specified the max and min values of y and x.

This is the code to create the map boundaries:

```
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="grey90")
```

This is the code for the plot:

```
mp <- NULL
mp <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=as.numeric(DDEjitter1), y=as.numeric(DDSjitter1))) +  
mapWorld +
Africablock + 
geom_point( size=2, alpha = 0.7) +
coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin=-20,
           xmax=60,
           ymin=-38,
           ymax=25),
       fill='transparent',
       col='black',
       size=0.1)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to directly use the `Africablock`  object to create the rectangle. 
I have several of these objects and I would like to put them in a list object to use for several maps.

here are some dummie data:

```
 data<-data.frame(DDEjitter1={runif(min = -180,max = 180,n=200)},DDSjitter1={runif(min = -90,max = 90,n=200)},id=1:200)
```

Comment: I do not find the object `mapWorld`. Do you use any specific package for that?

Comment: Moreover, you are referring to `data` and I guess, that this is your own data frame. Please give sample data or you risk downvoting , people can be strict here.

Comment: @Tjebo I've added the extra lines for the mapWorld object and the data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple function that extracts the limits from a `CoordCartesian` object, and uses them to construct a `geom_rect` object that you can use in the plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

rect_from_coord <- function(coord, ...) {
  geom_rect(
    mapping = aes_(
        xmin = coord$limits$x[1],
        xmax = coord$limits$x[2],
        ymin = coord$limits$y[1],
        ymax = coord$limits$y[2]
    ),
    ...
  )
}

coord <- coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2, 4), ylim = c(15, 25))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  rect_from_coord(coord, fill = 'transparent', col = 'black', size = 0.1)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).